# What is the difference between pkgbuild vs productbuild?

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line-interface, pkgbuild, productbuild

I am trying to create a .pkg installer for a CLI on macOS (Monterey). I have come across `pkgbuild` and `productbuild`.

They are already installed on my mac.

Where can i read more about what these CLIs do? (not only how to use).

What is the difference between the two?

---

I came across them from this stack overflow thread:
[Making macOS Installer Packages which are Developer ID ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-macos-installer-packages-which-are-developer-id-ready)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [`pkgbuild`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/pkgbuild/) builds a macOS Installer *"component package"*. A *component package* contains a payload to be installed by the macOS Installer. Throughout the man pages, component packages are also referred to as *"packages"*. Although a component package can be installed on its own, it is typically incorporated into a *"product archive"*, along with a distribution file and localized resources, using `productbuild`.
- [`productbuild`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/productbuild/) builds a *"product archive"* for the macOS Installer or the Mac App Store. A *product archive* is also a file to be used by the macOS Installer, but it [can contain multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38840657/7852784) *component packages* to be installed. And by using `productbuild` to create a product archive, you can add elements to customize the installation process for users (such as your own text, license agreement, localized resources, logo etc.). You will see product archives also referred to as *"distribution packages"* <sup>[1](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/09/on-distribution-packages/) [2](https://scriptingosx.com/2020/12/platform-support-in-macos-installer-packages-pkg/)</sup> and *"installer packages"* <sup>[3](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701581#701581021)</sup>. If you want to upload your bundle/app to the Mac App Store, then you need to create a product archive for it with `productbuild` rather than only using `pkgbuild`.

Confusingly the output files (*component packages* and *product archives*) of the two commands both have the same extension (`.pkg`). But you can find out more about a `.pkg` by looking at the contents, which you can see by right clicking it and selecting *Show Package Contents* or by running `pkgutil --expand my-package.pkg path/to/expand`. <sup>[4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15665/486314)</sup>

Hopefully some of those links provide you with some more reading material about what the commands do. [This](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2014/06/os-x-creating-packages-from-command_2.html) blogpost details more about using the two commands, and [this](https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd08744) is a good blog post outlining how the commands can be used to create a custom `.pkg` installer for a macOS application.